# When is composition of two linear projections onto two different subspaces commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra

(Gilbert Strang, Linear Algebra, Section 4.2, Problem 34)

> $P_1$ and $P_2$ are projections onto subspaces S and T. What is the requirement on those subspaces to have $P_1 P_2$ = $P_2 P_1$ ?

My attempt : There are 3 possibilities (i) $S=T$ (ii) $S \subset T$ (iii) $ T \subset S$.
The first possibility is easy to prove. Therefore, I will try to prove that either (ii) or (iii) must be the case.

Let $C(S)$ be column space of S and $C(T)$ be the column space of T.

For any vector $v$ , $P_2v \in C(T)$ . In particular, for $v=P_1 a$, $P_2P_1 a \in C(T)$ . Since $P_1 a \in C(S)$, we have

$P_1 a \in C(S) \implies P_2P_1 a \in C(T)$ ......(1)

Similarly,

$P_2 a \in C(T) \implies P_1P_2 a \in C(S)$ ......(2)

Now, if we can somehow show that $P_1P_2 a \in C(S) \implies P_2P_1 a \in C(T)$ , we are essentially saying  $S \subset T$(Is this right? Does subset relation between column-spaces imply subset relation between their sub-spaces ?). But I am not sure how to go about it. Any hints ?

Comment: There is no such thing as _the_ projection onto a subspace. Are these orthogonal projections? Also there are a lot more possible relations among $S,T$ to consider than $S=T$, $S\subset T$ and $S\supset T$.

Answer (score -1):

There is an exercise showing that, $P_1$ and $P_2$ being two projections of a vector space $E$, onto respectively $S$ and $T$ 
$$P_1 \circ P_2 = P_2 \circ P_1 $$ 
$$ \Leftrightarrow $$ 
$$ \small  E = (Img (P_1) \cap Img(P_2)) \oplus (Img(P_1) \cap \ker(P_2)) \oplus (Img(P_2) \cap \ker(P_1)) \oplus (\ker(P_1) \cap \ker(P_2)) = \\ 
 (S \cap T) \oplus (S\cap \ker(P_2)) \oplus(T \cap \ker(P_1)) \oplus (\ker(P_1) \cap \ker(P_2))   $$
but it's not a straightforward demonstration ...